# Error occurred prerendering page... TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading 'props')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, build

#nextjs #SSG #pages version 13.2
Im trying to use MDX plugins to build a blog, and I want to handle frontmatter on my (SSG) pages.
but I keep getting an error

Error occurred prerendering page "/(layout)/MDXLayout". ....
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Importantly it works perfectly with npm run dev, and fails at build.

tried so many ways to get around it, I do not understand why it breaks at build time.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-blog",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=9.5.0",
    "node": ">=18.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.2.4",
    "@next/mdx": "^13.2.4",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "reading-time": "^1.5.0",
    "rehype-accessible-emojis": "^0.3.2",
    "rehype-autolink-headings": "^6.1.1",
    "rehype-pretty-code": "^0.9.4",
    "rehype-prism": "^2.2.0",
    "rehype-slug": "^5.1.0",
    "remark-frontmatter": "^4.0.1",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "remark-mdx": "^2.3.0",
    "remark-rehype": "^10.1.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mdx": "^2.0.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.6",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "plugins": [
      "preset-lint-consistent",
      "preset-lint-recommended",
      "preset-lint-markdown-style-guide",
      "preset-prettier"
    ]
  }
}
```